# Calculate bounding box width and height from given coordinates(x,y)

Tags: javascript, geometry, bounding-box

I have a list of coordinates

```
const coords = [{x:10, y:20}, {x:5, y:6}, {x:1, y:25}, {x:11, y:2}];
```

And I am wondering is there a way to calculate bounding box width and height having only these coordinates?

Comment: Sure, such way exists, but it seems to me, that this is your homework task, so you'd better try to do it by yourself.

Comment: And if you've tried, then you can add some code to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `map()` function transform the input array into array of `x` or `y` values. You can then feed these transformed arrays to `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` to get `left`, `right`, `bottom` and `top` to compute the `bounding box`. When you have the `bounding box`, the width and height calculation is straight forward (subtract min from max). See code snippet below.

```js
const coords = [{x:10, y:20}, {x:5, y:6}, {x:1, y:25}, {x:11, y:2}];
const xArr = coords.map(c => c.x);
const yArr = coords.map(c => c.y);

const l = Math.min(...xArr);
const r = Math.max(...xArr);
const b = Math.min(...yArr);
const t = Math.max(...yArr);

const width  = r - l;
const height = t - b;
console.log(width, height);
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess, that would be the difference between minimum and maximum values of `x` (width) and `y` (height).

[image]

While the [obvious way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63824635/11299053) to calculate those may seem to be using of `Math.max()`/`Math.min()` over extracted arrays of coordinates, it requires looping source array several times unnecessarily, whereas single pass (e.g. with `Array.prototype.reduce()`) is quite enough and may perform [noticeably faster](http://jsbench.me/qxkewly535/1), when input array is relatively large:

```js
const points = [{x:10, y:20}, {x:5, y:6}, {x:1, y:25}, {x:11, y:2}],

      {width, height} = points.reduce((acc, {x,y}) => {
            if(!acc.mX || x < acc.mX){
              acc.mX = x
            } else if (!acc.MX || x > acc.MX){
              acc.MX = x
            }
            if(!acc.mY || y < acc.mY){
              acc.mY = y
            } else if (!acc.MY || y > acc.MY){
              acc.MY = y
            }
            acc.width = acc.MX - acc.mX
            acc.height = acc.MY - acc.mY
            return acc
          }, {width: 0, height: 0})
          
console.log(`width: ${width}; height: ${height}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this snippet. Guess this is an approach to start with.

---

**Some explanations**:

We're calculating the minX, maxX, minY and maxY values from the coords set using `Math.operationMinOrMax(...coords.map(c => c.propertyXorY))`.

- The min-x coordinate of the bounding box (*=> left corner*) is the minX value.
- The min-y coordinate of the bounding box (*=> top*) is the minY value.

---

- The max-x coordinate of the bounding box (*=> right corner*) is the maxX value.
- The max-y coordinate of the bounding box (*=> bottom*) is the maxY value.

---

Size (property **w** and **h**) can be calulated by substracting `maxX - minX` and `maxY - minY`.

```js
const boundingBox = (coords) => {
  const minX = Math.min(...coords.map(c => c.x)), maxX = Math.max(...coords.map(c => c.x));
  const minY = Math.min(...coords.map(c => c.y)), maxY = Math.max(...coords.map(c => c.y));
  return {
    x: minX,
    y: minY,
    w: maxX - minX,
    h: maxY - minY
  }
}
console.log(
  boundingBox( [ {x:10,y:5}, {x:100,y:0}, {x:100,y:100}, {x:12,y:50}, {x:0,y:100}, {x:27,y:22} ])
);
```